# Any command to find list of compilers in windows command line?

Tags: command-line, installation, cmd.exe, compile

Is there any command like

```
dpkg --list | grep compiler
```

(that is for terminal on ubuntu)

[image]

to run and find the list of already installed compilers in windows command line?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPKG_(software)

Comment: No, there isn't.  PERIOD.  Any solution offered will not be like the one you demonstrate above.  Many compilers on windows don't even have installs (arm-linaro for example) so no way to know even where the user might have unzipped it.  You will need to know what ones you are looking for an have a method to try to identify if it installed.  If you are curious about SPECIFIC compilers.. that is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Caveats:

- Not all software installed in a Windows environment will register itself in such a way that you can find it in a single place.
- Not all software installed in a Windows environment will have a name or a description that provides the identifying information you are looking for, such as "compiler".

With those caveats in mind, well-behaved software will register itself for inclusion in the `Add and Remove Programs` or `Programs and Features` control panels. So, you can search through the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` section of the registry. This use of `reg query` should do it:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /f "compiler" /s
```

- The `/f` specifies the data to search for. The search is case-insensitive. (Unless you add a `/c` switch.)
- The `/s` parameter makes the query recursive, so it also queries subkeys. (You probably don't need this for the particular case of the Uninstall key.)
- If you have anything that recorded itself in the 32-bit section of the registry, you'll need to add the `/reg:32` switch.

Like this:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /f "compiler" /s /reg:32
```